# How to Save downloaded state of progress bar using AFNetworkig?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, download

I use Table View and Embed In to Navigation make a custom cell and set a Progress bar and a downloading button on it. And i set multiple URLs and save all URLs in array and set those array on table view. I use AFNetworking to Downloading via URL. I set all methods on NSObject class and call that method on table view cell.

```
- (void)startDownload{
    if(!self.isDownloading){
        self.isDownloading = YES;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.DownloadString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        NSString *fullPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];

        [operation setOutputStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:fullPath append:NO]];

        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

            self.Progress = (float)((float)totalBytesRead/(float)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
            NSLog(@"progress: %f",self.Progress);
        }];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"RES: %@", [[[operation response] allHeaderFields] description]);

            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"ERR: %@", [error description]);
            } else {
                // NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
                 //   long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"ERR: %@", [error description]);
        }];
        [operation start];
    }
}
```

now I have a issue if downloading was start and I Press back button and again come to table view the progress Bar is again "0" Downloading Button is again available.
I want to save the state of my progress bar when ever cell dequeue and I go back to the navigation or came back. I want Preserve my Downloading state and my progress bar state.
Is any One knows how to Save state of my Progress bar when I download a big file the progress bar is running on tableview cell when I came back Progress states preserved.

Comment: Store download data / progress outside of UI. Use UI to display data or progress. Maybe singleton manager for downloads or similar.

Comment: @Andy In my Downloader class there are 10 multiple URLs for downloading after apply Singleton to my Downloader class all my Progress bar working together and shared one Instance to all over. In this scenario Singleton is no the valid solution.

Comment: Well it is valid. You can store progress per URL and then use NSTimer to update visible cells with download progress. What I am saying is you need a better abstraction for that and you have to decouple user interface from actual download.